# NestJs - ParseUUIDPipe - Validation failed (uuid vundefined is expected)

Tags: nestjs

I have a basic controller setup:

```
@Controller('')
export class AController {
 @Get(':id')
  async getThing(@Param('id', ParseUUIDPipe) id: string): Promise<RegisterRead[] | IntervalRead[]> {
      return id
  }
}
```

And I get the following error:

```
{
    "statusCode": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "Validation failed (uuid vundefined is expected)"
}
```

Also see: https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/2960

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This issue was caused because I did not have a version specified. It shows version as an optional field, but it appears to be required:

```
new ParseUUIDPipe({version: '4'})
```

Comment: could you accept your own answer - if you can - please ? :)

Comment: Just an update to this - the version is apparently no longer required, and `@Param('id', ParseUUIDPipe) id: string` should work

Answer (score 1):

With decorator helper:

```
import { Param, ParseUUIDPipe } from '@nestjs/common';

export const UUIDParam = (name: string) => Param(name, new ParseUUIDPipe());

// Your controller endpoint
@Patch(':id')
public async updateOne(@UUIDParam('id') id: string): any;
```

Docs link [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/pipes#built-in-pipes)